# cassandara with Etl spoon

Tags: cassandra, pentaho, etl, spoon

```
An unexpected error occurred in Spoon:  
Could not initialize class org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket
    at org.pentaho.cassandra.legacy.CassandraConnection.openConnection(CassandraConnection.java:234)
    at org.pentaho.cassandra.legacy.CassandraConnection.checkOpen(CassandraConnection.java:151)
    at org.pentaho.cassandra.legacy.CassandraConnection.setKeyspace(CassandraConnection.java:174)
    at org.pentaho.cassandra.legacy.LegacyKeyspace.setKeyspace(LegacyKeyspace.java:93)
    at org.pentaho.cassandra.legacy.CassandraConnection.getKeyspace(CassandraConnection.java:277)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.cassandrainput.CassandraInputDialog.popupSchemaInfo(CassandraInputDialog.java:926)
    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.cassandrainput.CassandraInputDialog$12.widgetSelected(CassandraInputDialog.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1227)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7368)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:8673)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:625)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:134)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just hit the very same problem.
After some investigation I fixed by copying followin files

- data-integration/lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar
- data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.3.jar
- data-integration/plugins/pentaho-big-data-plugin/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.3.jar

to .../data-integration/plugins/pentaho-cassandra-plugin/lib/ directory

Comment: Still broken:

Unable to open dialog for this step
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
 at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.<clinit>(TIOStreamTransport.java:38)
 at org.pentaho.cassandra.legacy.CassandraConnection.openConnection(CassandraConnection.java:234)
...